# Gui never updates. Data.mdb will not sync. Need handholding guide. Please help

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization, daemon

The GUI Wallet will download blocks from node.moneroworld.com but I see no blockchain on my HDD.  I tried monerod.exe and get the following:

sync_info
Height: 1, target: 1 (100%)
Downloading at 0 kB/s
2 peers
212.83.175.67:18080       0000000000000000  0  0 kB/s, 0 blocks / 0 MB queued
163.172.182.165:18080     0000000000000000  0  0 kB/s, 0 blocks / 0 MB queued
0 spans, 0 MB

Comment: Which operating system? Which version of the software? If you were previously using a remote node, you would not have a local copy of the blockchain.  If you run `monerod`, it will start syncing from the beginning of the blockchain.  That may be what the initial lines are after starting `monerod` for the first time.  Did it hang there, or did it continue to sync?

Answer (score 1):

node.moneroworld.com is what keeps the blockchain for you, meaning (1) you don't need to download it and (2) you're at its mercy for some kinds of MITM attacks.

If you want to get the blockchain on your computer, set your own computer (127.0.0.1) as the node address, instead of node.moneroworld.com. Then start the daemon when asked, and it'll start downloading the chain.